# Twilio Glass SMS

Tags: google-glass

I installed and activated the Twilio Glass SMS in "myglass" and once I turned it on was assigned a twilio glass number. Now I'm wondering, how I send text messages? There is not an option on my glass to do it. When I say "okay glass, send a message" It only emails. I was hoping this app would help me since I am a iphone user and text messaging on glass only comes standard for android phones. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

At this point there is no way to hook into Glass voice actions. However, you can receive incoming SMS messages to your Twilio phone number that you got through the app and they will appear on your Glass device. You may then reply to those messages using the Reply feature on Glass once you receive the message.

**Update:** You can read a tutorial on how to send and receive SMS messages via Twilio using the Glass Mirror API on our blog: [Using Google Glass, Twilio, Ruby, and Sinatra to Send and Receive SMS Messages](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/05/using-google-glass-twilio-ruby-and-sinatra-to-send-and-receive-sms-messages.html)